# How to extract parts using regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

For example you have the following string:

```
$text = "word1:text1@atpart/foo/do/myfood$textfinal";
```

The function will work like:

```
$parts = array();    
extract( $regular_exp, $text, $parts );
```

In the parts array we will get this:

```
$parts[0] = "word1";
$parts[1] = "text1";
$parts[2] = "atpart";
$parts[3] = "/foo/do/myfood";
$parts[4] = "textfinal";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this data come from? This looks very similar to a URL. Any chance of actually getting it in URL format?

Answer (score 4):

This may not be what you are after, but the format you show looks almost like a URL with a `username:password@domain` authentication in front. If you can get the last `$` to be served as a `?`, it *might* be an idea to use `parse_url()` to parse it.

```
$string =  "word1:text1@atpart/foo/do/myfood?textfinal"; // notice the ?

$string = "none://".$string; // We need to add a protocol for this to work

print_r (parse_url($string));
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
         [scheme] => none 
         [host] => atpart 
         [user] => word1 
         [pass] => text1 
         [path] => /foo/do/myfood 
         [query] => textfinal )
```

the advantage of this would be that it's pretty flexible if one or more parts can be missing in the incoming data. If that's not an issue, a regex may be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$parts = preg_split('/[:@\$]+/', $text);
```

Comment: Although it doesn't hurt to do so, the `$` needs no escaping inside a character class.

Comment: this doesn't split `atpart` from the path-like following piece

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, this matches the proposed example:

```
preg_match('#(.*?):(.*?)@(.*?)(/.*?)\$(.*)#', $text, $parts);
```

note that you will get the parts starting at index 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$delims=':@$';
$word = strtok('word1:text1@atpart/foo/do/myfood$textfinal',$delims);
while ( $word!==false ) {
    foreach( explode('/',$word,2) as $tmp){
        $words[]=$tmp;
    }
    $word = strtok($delims);
}
var_dump($words);
```

On one hand this is probably overkill. On the other hand, this may be more flexible depending on how different the string can be.

Demo: http://codepad.org/vy5b9yX7

Docs: http://php.net/strtok